# Does there exist a shape(s) in n-dimensions that do not have a centroid?

Tags: geometry

I was curious to whether there are any shapes in n-dimensions that do not have a centroid, and if so, which would it be?

Comment: A parabola, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define what you mean by a shape.  The $x$ centroid  of a set $V$ is defined as $\frac {\int x\; \text dV}{\int \; \text dV}$.  If either of these integrals fails to exist, the centroid does not exist.  One way for an integral not to exist is for the set to be unbounded in such a way that the integral does not converge.  In two dimensions we could take the region $x\gt 1, 0 \le y \le \frac 1{x^2}$.  The area converges nicely, but the upper integral does not converge.  Another way is if the set $V$ is not integrable like the sets used in the Banach-Tarski paradox.  Another way is for the denominator to be zero.
If the set is finite, you can replace the integrals with sums over the points.
If the set is infinite but measure zero you need to think about how to define the centroid.  Whether these qualify as shapes is the question.  If a shape is required to be an integrable bounded set, the centroid must exist.

Comment: Or $V$ has measure zero, then centroid is again undefined.

Comment: Thank you for this explenation! I was thinking of bounded sets, I forgot to mention that and I think my mathematical knowledge is yet too little to know how to define a shape properly. So does that mean that if the set would be bounded and integrable and V has not a measure of zero, then all shapes have a centroid?

Comment: Yes, because the only way the numerator can fail if $V$ is integrable is to become infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The centroid can be outside the range/domain bounds of a given shape but physical entities/ dimensions do not vanish.

Comment: Yes I do understand that a centroid can be outside the range/domain bounds of a given shape. But does that mean that every shape has a centroid? Despite whether it is inside or outside its range/domain boundaries?

Comment: Certainly intuitive, yes.

Comment: And is there a known proof for that every shape in n-dimensional space has a centroid?